# android studio connection refused: connect when add classpath to top root build gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, classpath

I'm trying to add classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' to build.gradle root file, but i'm getting error

Error: connection refused: connect

when i change app gradle file it works with only the top root gradle file i'm getting this error.

I use a proxy that i configure in gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=****han1987
systemProp.http.proxyHost=*****
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
systemProp.http.proxyUser=***amassi
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
} 

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Do you have the proxy setting in `gradle.properties` in your root project or in your app project? And can you show your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: It's in my root project, it s really strange this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution 
i had

```
 systemProp.http.proxyPassword=****han1987
 systemProp.http.proxyHost=*****
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
 systemProp.http.proxyUser=***amassi
 systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

i add https like this :

```
 systemProp.https.proxyPassword=****han1987
 systemProp.https.proxyHost=*****
 systemProp.https.proxyUser=***amassi
 systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

And it's correct my problem, but i dont undestand why it work for app and not for app root.